# Stop iPad MoviePlayer video when a view is changed

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm writing my first iPad app that plays a video on a portion of the screen. My problem is that if the user changes to another view while the video is playing, the audio keeps playing in the background. I assume I have to add something to the "viewDidUnload" method but I'm not sure what to do. Any ideas? Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding

```
[myMoviePlayer pause]; // assume myMoviePlayer is an instance variable
[myMoviePlayer stop];
myMoviePlayer = nil;
```

to your viewWillDisappear method.